# Join of random variables - relation to max

Tags: probability, martingales, finance

On Wikipedia in the article [Snell envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell_envelope) author uses 'join' operation on random variables. Following line is relevant:

$$ U_n = X_n \lor \mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[U_{n+1} | \mathcal F_n] \quad \text{for} \ \ n \neq N$$

Having read Wikipedia's definition it seems like it could be replaced by max. Is it a deliberately confusing notation or is there something to it?

Comment: Well in the case of 2 random variables then the max is the join

Comment: Or should I say the join is the max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X\vee Y=\max(X,Y)$. Wikipedia is being obtuse by referring to $\vee$ as "join" when "max" is a clearer description.

Comment: Is this a fashionable jargon in some area of mathematics? This is literally first time I've seen this notation used anywhere

Comment: The notation is not uncommon in probability theory. It is used extensively in Durrett's probability text, e.g.